# Display ads accessibility requirements

Tags: html, accessibility, ads, wai-aria

I'm adding WCAG accessibility to non-Google display ads. I produce ads using transparent PNGs that tween to 0,0 to animate and build the ad and to show the focus/hover state. Our text in the ad is part of the PNGs. My simplified code below is:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta content="width=300,height=250" name="ad.size">
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
        <title>300x250</title>
        <link href="300x250.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script defer src="https://url.com/script-that-animates-images/" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <a href="https://url.com" title="Advertisement — Text that repeats the image's text. Call to action." id="rolloverCatch">
                <div id="content">
                    <!-- animated images that include the text -->
                    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/250">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've added `title` to the anchor — on hover the image text is repeated — but is that correct and enough? (e.g., `alt` is for images, `title` for links, is this correct?) I realize the ideal situation would be to render plain text but what more can be done to better align with accessibility requirements using only images in a display ad? On the images themselves, should I be adding `aria-hidden=true`? Is there an appropriate reference to use here?

Concerning Google display ads, is the accessibility functions added within that system? I'm tracking I **do not** have anchors within the uploaded HTML source, should Google display ads have `alt` text on the top-most image instead?

I'm using [accessibleweb.com](https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/ads-site-need-follow-accessibility-guidelines/#:%7E:text=Display%20ads%20do%20need%20to,operable%20with%20only%20a%20keyboard.) and [Disability Studies Quarterly](https://dsq-sds.org/article/view/281/311) as references for the above but I'm having trouble finding timely or better resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your example the most natural way to do it is to add an `alt` attribute to the `<img>` element:

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="https://url.com" id="rolloverCatch">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- animated images that include the text -->
            <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/250" alt="Advertisement — Text that repeats the image's text. Call to action.">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

When the `<a>` element has a text, or another element having itself an accessible name between its opening and closing tags, it takes that as its own accessible name.

And by the way, all the images that have something meaningful must have an alternative text (with `alt`, `aria-label` or `aria-albelledby`).

Comment: According to https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H30.html : "When an image is the only content of a link, the text alternative for the image describes the unique function of the link." Example 2 is the most similar: `<a href="routes.html"><img src="topo.gif" alt="Current routes at Boulders Climbing Gym" /></a>` Don't need title. Will give other layers `aria-hidden="true"` and defer to the single image's alt text. Thanks!